# A part of the div is not getting updated even though a request and response was done properly

Tags: angularjs

I have following controller. Which has a custom html **show-chat** defined using directive.

```
<div id='homeDiv' ng-controller="bloggingHomeController">
  <div id ='chatAreaDiv' style="float:left;width:25%;">
    <h3>Messages</h3>
    <show-chat></show-chat>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Following is the directive definition of **show-chat**

```
 appDirective.directive('showChat', function() {
        return {        
            restrict: 'E', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
            // template: '',
            templateUrl: 'partials/chat.html',
            replace: true
        };
    });
```

chat.html is as follows.

```
<div id='chatHtmlDiv' ng-controller='chatController'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="aChat in allChats" style="list-style-type: none;">
      <b style="color:red;">{{aChat.message}}</b><br/>
      <cite>by {{aChat.createdBy}} on {{aChat.createdDate | date}}</cite>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <textarea id='chatBox' ng-model='chatMessage'></textarea>
  <br/>
  <button id='postChatButton' ng-click = postChatMessage()>Post Message</button>    
</div>
```

Inside bloggingHomeController i have the following.

```
app.controller('chatController', function($scope, $route, chatService) {
    chatService.getChat()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.allChats = data;
    }, function(error) {

    });
    $scope.postChatMessage = function() {
        var c = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.chatMessage));
        chatService.save(c)
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.chatMessage = '';
        }, function(error) {

        })

        chatService.getChat()
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.allChats = data;
            $route.reload();
        }, function(error) {

        });
    };
});
```

When postChatMessage() is being called from chat.html a request is made to the database to get the chat messages .
The issue is $scope.allChats is getting updated with the new value but 
show-chat doesnot show the updated data.
May i know is this not getting updated ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're reloading the route, so this controller and its directives are most probably thrown away and replaced by new instances.

Answer (score 0):

It can happens because you try to save new message and receive list of messages in the same time.

Try to move receiving of new messages inside to success callback for chat message save request

```
chatService.save(c)
  .then(function(data) {
    $scope.chatMessage = '';
    // Receive new messages here
  }, function(error) {

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this `$scope.$apply()` after set the your response to models.